# Table cell like view for HTML list

Tags: html, css

Is this possible?
How can i make my list(`<li>`) elements to be seen like table cells?

Update:

- I need table look and feel, but also i need to use `li` tag,
- I need to conserve the indentations

[I do not need like this](http://jsfiddle.net/b5KH3), I want the view when I delete the CSS ([like this](http://jsfiddle.net/b5KH3/1)).

I found solution [here](http://www.naprej.com/ul_li_table)

Thanks

Comment: The odds are you should be approaching this differently

Comment: have a google of `display:table-cell`

Comment: A little more explanation of what you are trying to achieve and what you have tried so far would be useful.

Comment: @Pete i have tried <li style="display:table:cell"> and my list elements layout become broken down

Comment: To be able to help you, you need to post the relevant HTML and CSS otherwise we are guessing.

Comment: What do you mean by "look like a table cell"? You want borders around the content that's inside the <li>?

Comment: @akinuri yes, exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to behave exactly like table add the following CSS:

```
ul, ol {
    display: table;
}
li {
    display: table-row;
}
```

Thought, for `IE` it works since version 8.

Here's the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/b5KH3/2/)**

Comment: but i do not want one li set to be on same row, when i have tried above my list view become broken down

Comment: @kulkata, can you provide some jsfiddle or code examples? It's hard to tell what obstacles can be met here.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/b5KH3/ i do not need like this, i want the view when i delete the css:http://jsfiddle.net/b5KH3/1/

Comment: To be clear, i need a treetable, collapsable nodes, and also cell borders for every line. I know there is a jquery treetable plugin but now i have a angular list tree plugin and want to use it.

Comment: Thanks very much thanks, that's it. li {
    display: table-row;
}

Comment: But borders are still invisible, if i add border-collapse:collapse it collapses

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Paulie_D. Please tell us little more about what you are trying to achieve. 
But if you want to create a table like look and feel, you can add `float` to `li` and give padding or fixed height and width to individual `<li>`. You can also specify `<ul>` width, so it will wrap the `<li>` at a specific width.